# TapGestureRecognizer мешает работе PanGestureRecognizer

Tags: c#, maui

В моем коде я считываю перемещение пальца по определенной области, с помощью `PanGestureRecognizer`. И у меня появилась проблема, дело в том что, при двойном нажатии не вызывается ивент `PanGestureRecognizer-а`, как я понимаю это потому что срабатывает `TapGestureRecognizer`. Вопрос заключается в том как это можно исправить.

Чтобы проблема была более понятной, у меня есть [видео](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uMDyMTX1MjrfDNnXKkwQSEANrI0fa6N-/view?usp=sharing).

Вот код:

```
<Border>
    <Border.GestureRecognizers>
        <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="Touchpad_PanUpdate"/>
    </Border.GestureRecognizers>
</Border>
```

Бэк:

```
private void Touchpad_PanUpdate(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.StatusType == GestureStatus.Running)
    {
        DebugRunningLabel.Text = "x/y: " + Math.Round(e.TotalX, 2) + " " + Math.Round(e.TotalY, 2);
    }
}
```